# ClassCastException, при добавлении объекта в TreeSet

Tags: java

Пример:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

   public class Cat {

        private static int age;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Set<Cat> a = new TreeSet<>();
            a.add(new Cat()); // ClassCastException при добавлении
            Comparable<Cat> comparable = new Comparable<>() { 
                @Override
                public int compareTo(Cat o){
                    return age - o.age;
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Текст ошибки:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class anonymouseClasses.Cat cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable (anonymouseClasses.Cat is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Comparable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1291)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:536)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
    at anonymouseClasses.Cat.main(Cat.java:13)
```

Comment: Если исключение возникает при добавлении, то почему вы спрашиваете про компаратор?

Comment: Поменял вопрос.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки. Будет понятнее в чём её суть.

Comment: Добавлено******

Comment: Почему этот код не работает?

Comment: Добавил импорт Set и TreeSet, теперь должно правильно свалиться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объекты, которые Вы добавляете в TreeSet должны реализовывать интерфейс `Comparable`, о чем написано в `Javadoc` к `TreeSet`:

> ```
> /**
>  * Constructs a new, empty tree set, sorted according to the
>  * natural ordering of its elements.  All elements inserted into
>  * the set must implement the {@link Comparable} interface.
>  * Furthermore, all such elements must be <i>mutually
>  * comparable</i>: {@code e1.compareTo(e2)} must not throw a
>  * {@code ClassCastException} for any elements {@code e1} and
>  * {@code e2} in the set.  If the user attempts to add an element
>  * to the set that violates this constraint (for example, the user
>  * attempts to add a string element to a set whose elements are
>  * integers), the {@code add} call will throw a
>  * {@code ClassCastException}.
>  */
> ```

---

Не понятно почему у Вас поле `age` статическое, скорее всего это ошибка...

---

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Cat implements Comparable<Cat>{

    private int age;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Cat> a = new TreeSet<>();
        a.add(new Cat());
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Cat o) {
        return age - o.age;
    }
}
```

---

Вариант номер 2 - явно задать компаратор у `TreeSet`

```
public class Cat {

    private int age;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Cat> a = new TreeSet<>((o1, o2) -> o1.age - o2.age);
        a.add(new Cat());
    }

}
```

Comment: То есть анонимно переопределить compareTo - нельзя? Понимаю, что в этом скорее всего нет смысла. В общем, был кое-какой пример без generic, говорилось о том, что теперь можно при помощи анонимных классов можно переопределять compareTo, я добавил туда generic. А ещё, причём тут static, дело ещё и в этом?

Comment: @АльбертПетров дополнил ответ